# Can we model something up to an approximation which fundamentally does not have a mathematical description?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics

Usually physicists assume there exists a mathematical description of reality and their models are mere approximations. So here's something that I wasn't sure about:

Let's say I have a phenomena which cannot be exactly modelled by mathematics. But it can be modelled up to an approximation.

Is the latter even a possibility? Are there any examples or hypothetical constructions?

Comment: One does not need to assume any "mathematical description of reality" *a la* Tegmark to do the modeling, whether it works and to what precision will come out in the process. There are ontologies where all laws of nature are only approximate, e.g. [Cartwright's nomological machines](https://www.thur.de/philo/project/cartwright.htm) and [entity realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_realism) more generally. And there are plenty of phenomena that cannot be modeled by mathematics very precisely for the foreseeable future, most of biology and psychology, for example. Is implies can.

Comment: For the examples you give biology and psychology. I thought the problem was that we cannot model it in a computable fashion. For biology if I started it with the equations of motion of a molecule and the aggregated my way until I have the entire system. I think I can capture the time evolution of the system.

Comment: Equations of motion are imprecise to begin with, and it only gets worse with "aggregation". You'll need that very "mathematical reality", which is in doubt, plus strong reductionism, to get this going. Entity realists reject both, as do many others. But even assuming platonism with ontological reductionism, if they are only divinely accessible they make no difference as far as our practice is concerned.

Comment: Here, you are assuming that _we can_. But we don't, far from it. The question comes from the opposite front: to what extent can we mathematically model the objects of the world?

Comment: I was hoping more for some mathematical proof of existence of such a system

Comment: If a phenomenon cannot in principle be modeled mathematically, then how do you know that you have a phenomenon?

Comment: Of course. Consider the entirety of Economics. The whole purpose of mathematics is abstractions, finding commanalities that work 'well enough' (see Cartwright, 'How The Laws of Physics Lie' ) but ignoring things like differences between individual humans when studying inferences from societal averages even though they may well not apply to everyone

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Although the biological world obeys the physical laws, it has the laws of its own, not reducible to the properties of atoms/molecules/elementary particles - a phenomenon known as *emergence*. See [this discussion in physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/625503/247642) Also Phil Anderson's [More is different](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have a phenomena which cannot be exactly modelled by mathematics. But it can be modelled up to an approximation.
>
> Is the latter even a possibility? Are there any examples or hypothetical constructions?

Yes, it is possible.

Before I tell you the answer to your question, here is a warm-up: the set of real numbers that are [definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number) in a particular formal system such as ZFC, is much smaller than the set of real numbers. Why? Well, a definable number is a number for which there exists a formula in the formal system, which is satisfied by exactly one real number. But the set of formulas in the formal system is only countably infinite, whereas the set of real numbers is much larger: uncountably infinite. So the vast majority of the real numbers can't get a defining formula of their own.

Similarly, most phenomena that might exist, can't be exactly matched to a formal model. There are just too many variations of phenomena that might exist, and too few models (only countably many models).

As a specific example, think of a universe in which the speed of light (when measured in a particular unit system that does not define an exact value for it) happens to be a real number that is not definable. In that universe (which might possibly be our own), there is no mathematical formula that can tell us exactly how far a photon travels in a second. The speed of light in that universe can be successively approximated, but can never be stated with perfect precision.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your "warm-up." You mention that the set of definable real numbers can be thought of as an approximation to the set of real numbers, but both sets can be exactly modelled by mathematics (in fact they can even be exactly modelled by constructive math), so I fail to see how this is an example. Also, you mention the possibility that the speed of light could not be a definable number, but since the speed of light is a dimensionful quantity, it's value can be fixed at whatever number we choose, whether that be 1 or 299792458.

Comment: I think he was thinking of something like the fine structure constant?

Comment: @Sandejo The speed of light suffices when measured in a particular unit system. The fine structure constant would suffice too. I didn't say anything about whether the real numbers can be exactly "modeled" by mathematics. (In fact, they can't be, due to Godel's incompleteness theorem; any formal system modeling the real numbers will have many formulas to which it cannot assign a truth value. But that's a different discussion).

Answer (score 0):

**Can we model something up to an approximation which fundamentally does not have a mathematical description?**

Yes. The process of induction is a process of elimination which yields only an approximation of what a phenomenon looks like. Induction produces a picture of what something is *not*. On this point, Karl Popper got it right.

An inductive conclusion does not necessarily involve mathematics. Political and military decisions, for example, can be based on induction, but involve assessments of risk which are not easily translated into mathematical terms; instead, the assessment must be described only as high, medium, or low.